# deedle and linq FillMissing values

Tags: c#, interpolation, deedle

Im trying to figure out how to use deedle to fill in some missing values in a list and its proving to be quite a headache, there are no real examples in c# i can find (it all centres around F#)

I have  a collection of objects and I want to calculate the average of the value before and the value after in the list and assign it to the missing value.  Ive created a frame below

```
var dfObjects = Frame.FromRecords(prices);
```

so I now want to perform the calculations, but I just cant work out how.  There is an F# example which supposedly does just what im after, but there is no C# version anywhere.

Heres the F# version

```js
// Fill missing values using interpolation function
ozone |> Series.fillMissingUsing (fun k -> 
  // Get previous and next values
  let prev = ozone.TryGet(k, Lookup.ExactOrSmaller)
  let next = ozone.TryGet(k, Lookup.ExactOrGreater)
  // Pattern match to check which values were available
  match prev, next with 
  | OptionalValue.Present(p), OptionalValue.Present(n) -> 
      (p + n) / 2.0
  | OptionalValue.Present(v), _ 
  | _, OptionalValue.Present(v) -> v
  | _ -> 0.0)
```

has anyone else done something similar ?

Ive managed to get all the series within my list like this

```
var frameDate = dfObjects.IndexRows<object>("SettlementDate").SortRowsByKey();
```

inspecting the object at runtime the data property gives me 4 series, two of which are the ones with missing values, how on earth do I interpolate values that are mising in these series ?  The F# example below uses FillMissingUsing, this isnt available in C#.  Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

The one notable difference is that the F# example shows how to fill missing data in a series, but you are interested in filling data in a whole data frame. The best way to do this is to process individual columns (those with missing data) independently.

Given a data frame `df` that contains a column named `Whatever`, you can fill the missing values using the above logic and replace the column in the data frame using:

```
var series = df.Columns["Whatever"].As<double>();
var filledSeries = series.FillMissing(dt => {
  var before = series.TryGet(dt, Lookup.ExactOrSmaller);
  var after = series.TryGet(dt, Lookup.ExactOrGreater);
  if (before.HasValue && after.HasValue) return (before.Value + after.Value) / 2.0
  else if (before.HasValue) return before.Value;
  else if (after.HasValue) return after.Value;
  else return 0.0;
});

df.ReplaceColumn("Whatever", filledSeries);
```